# When did $this start working?

Tags: php, static, object

Ok, all jokes aside...

I just noticed that I was able to refer to a static class propery using `$this::$name`. I don't remember ever running across that before since I always used `self::$name` or `$this->name` in my classes.

In what version of PHP did `$this` start working with static class properties?

Comment: Considering PHP allows you to statically call methods that are not static, $this is not $that surprising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the PHP5 changelog, v5.3.0 ( http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.0 ):

> Added support for dynamic access of
>   static members using $foo::myFunc().
>   (Etienne Kneuss)

So I suppose it's a fairly recent occurrence. :)

(Oh, and this refers to calling methods statically...I wonder if it's the same for accessing properties.)

Comment: "I wonder if it's the same for accessing properties." -- *Yes*, it is.